# PDF Equivalent of notepad++'s "Find all in current document"

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Notepad++ has a very useful feature where it lists all occurrence of a certain keyword in a document along with some bit of context. Is there a pdf equivalent of doing this? I dont want to press "next" 700 times to see something relevant to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which PDF viewer you use. [PDF-XChange Viewer](https://portableapps.com/apps/office/pdf-xchange-portable), for example, has the option to display a list of search results, in context.

[image: PDF-XChange Viewer Search Results]

In that application, click the "binocular" button to the left of the search box to display the *Search PDF* results panel.

[Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/), an excellent e-book library application, has a built-in e-book reader that provides similar functionality (albeit, it's slow to start up).

Comment: This owns. Thanks.